# Extend wireless range with a second router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I've read that using the router as an access point would be a solution, but is it possible to do this wirelessly, i.e without using a cat-5 cable? I haven't tried this yet, as I'm not sure if this is possible or whether there is a better way. Currently my setup is:

- A virgin super-hub modem/router downstairs with internet connectivity.
- A router (D-Link DIR-615) with no internet.
- Several Raspberry Pi's connected to the router with no internet, via ethernet.

My goal is to be able to network the Pi's together with access to internet. Looking for a solution.

Comment: Need more info... What have you tried already?  Where exactly are you getting stuck while attempting to accomplish your goal? Can your router be put into WiFi repeater mode? Can it run a 3rd party firmware? Which routers are in question?  etc.  Please consider editing this info into your question.

Comment: I'm a rookie, and I don't really know what I'm looking for, so I haven't tried anything yet. I'm looking for someone to give me suggestions. I'll update with what routers I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current hardware as described, you have two options:

1. Run a cable upstairs to your un-networked router.
2. Go out and buy a wireless bridge or repeater.

If your downstairs router has wi-fi capabilities, you can wirelessly network your Pis via that (assuming the signal is strong enough), but that won't get your upstairs router online without a wireless bridge.

Your typical wireless router quite simply lacks the capability of working as you're asking. It's designed to connect wireless clients to a wired network, but does not know how to route said wireless clients to a wireless network -- it doesn't even know how to connect to a wireless network itself! A bridge is the opposite of the typical wireless router (connects one or more wired clients to a wireless network), while a repeater is essentially a signal booster enabling wireless clients to connect to a wireless network they would not otherwise be able to see (due to the signal not reaching far enough).

Actually, the Pis do give you a third option (use one of them as a bridge or repeater), but that's not for the faint of heart, and even many pros would balk at that option.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

"If your downstairs router has wi-fi capabilities, you can wirelessly network your Pis via that",

The Raspberry Pi does not have any wireless capabilities, so this would not be an option. With this in mind, the repeater would also have to have several ethernet ports. Is there a way for my PC to act as the bridge between the routers? I'm not sure if my network card would be up to the trick - anyhow the model is a Macbook Pro retina 2013.

Comment: You can get USB wireless adapters for the Pis. But if you don't want to go that route, the bridge or running a Cat-5 cable upstairs are your only options. You might be able to use your PC to do that, but that's again in the realm of "very hard".

Answer (score 0):

install DD-WRT put it in AP Client mode and use it to receive from the virgin gateway over wifi and then send out to your PI's through ethernet connected to the dlink